# Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\user'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express, localdb

I'm trying to use a localDB as a local development database, but not matter what I do, I always get the exception `Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\user'.`

Example: right-click on `data connections` in the `server explorer` pane in vs2012. Select `add connection`, select `Microsoft SQL Server Database File` under `data source` and click continue. `Browse` to the location you want to save the database file, `use windows authentication`, click okay, see error.

I've tried removing all sql components from my machine and installing a fresh instance of SQL Server Express LocalDB several times to no avail.

How do I figure out which data user the database is expecting? How can I install it so that my current user can use it?

Any Help will be much appreciated.